# Divide function in pyspark

Tags: numpy, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have this dataframe on PySpark:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['red', 'banana', 1, 10], ['blue', 'banana', 2, 20], ['red', 'carrot', 3, 30],
    ['blue', 'grape', 4, 40], ['red', 'carrot', 5, 50], ['black', 'carrot', 6, 60],
    ['red', 'banana', 7, 70], ['red', 'grape', 8, 80]], schema=['color', 'fruit', 'v1', 'v2'])
```

I want to create a function that takes column v2 divided by column v1, with the condition:

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf

@pandas_udf('long', PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def pandas_div(a,b):
    if b == 0:
       return np.nan
    else:
       return (a/b)
```

However the result turn out to be like this

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The output that I want should be like this:

```
+---------+---------+---+
|color_new|fruit_new|div|
+---------+---------+---+
|      red|   banana|10 |
|     blue|   banana|20 |
|      red|   carrot|30 |
|     blue|    grape|40 |
|      red|   carrot|50 |
|    black|   carrot|60 |
|      red|   banana|70 |
|      red|    grape|80 |
+---------+---------+---+
```

Comment: What is the expected output? If column `v1` is `0` then new column should be `null` else divide `v2/v1` is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you needed was a `WHEN and OTHERWISE`. See example below

```
# Create data frame
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['red', 'banana', 1, 10], ['blue', 'banana', 2, 20], ['red', 'carrot', 3, 30],
    ['blue', 'grape', 4, 40], ['red', 'carrot', 5, 50], ['black', 'carrot', 6, 60],
    ['red', 'banana', 7, 70], ['red', 'grape', 8, 80], ['orange', 'grapefruit', 0, 100]], schema=['color', 'fruit', 'v1', 'v2'])

# display result
df.show()
+------+----------+---+---+
| color|     fruit| v1| v2|
+------+----------+---+---+
|   red|    banana|  1| 10|
|  blue|    banana|  2| 20|
|   red|    carrot|  3| 30|
|  blue|     grape|  4| 40|
|   red|    carrot|  5| 50|
| black|    carrot|  6| 60|
|   red|    banana|  7| 70|
|   red|     grape|  8| 80|
|orange|grapefruit|  0|100|
+------+----------+---+---+

# Import functions
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# apply case when
df1 = df.withColumn("divide", f.when(f.col("v1") == 0, None).otherwise(f.lit(f.col("v2")/f.col("v1"))))

# display result
df1.show()
+------+----------+---+---+------+
| color|     fruit| v1| v2|divide|
+------+----------+---+---+------+
|   red|    banana|  1| 10|  10.0|
|  blue|    banana|  2| 20|  10.0|
|   red|    carrot|  3| 30|  10.0|
|  blue|     grape|  4| 40|  10.0|
|   red|    carrot|  5| 50|  10.0|
| black|    carrot|  6| 60|  10.0|
|   red|    banana|  7| 70|  10.0|
|   red|     grape|  8| 80|  10.0|
|orange|grapefruit|  0|100|  null|
+------+----------+---+---+------+
```

Comment: So in this case I do not need to create a function and then apply it to a column, am I understand this correctly?

Comment: @Long_NgV You don't need to create a function